# How to add Intent (open browser) to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclicklistener

I want add onClickListener Intent to open a link into ArrayList.

I made class:

```
public class Element {
    private String mNazwa;
    private String mOpis;
    private Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    private int mImageResourceId;

    public Element (String nazwa, String opis, int imageResourceId, int link, Intent intent) {
       mNazwa = nazwa;
       mOpis = opis;
       mIntent = intent;
       mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;
   }

   public String getNazwa() {return mNazwa;}
   public String getOpis() {return mOpis;}
   public int getIntent() {return mIntent;}
   public int getmImageResourceId() {return mImageResourceId;}
}
```

and I want to call it in MainActivity with this code:

```
final ArrayList<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();
elements.add(new Element("dupa", "asdasdas", R.drawable.color_green,));
elements.add(new Element("dupa", "asdasdas", R.drawable.color_green));
elements.add(new Element("dupa", "asdasdas", R.drawable.color_green));

ElementAdapter adapter = new ElementAdapter(this, elements);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getLink);
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
});
```

Can you tell me where I am doing mistake? Is link an int? How to call it?

Comment: There's no array list here.

Comment: There's no array list of intents here. `Element` isn't an `Intent`.

Comment: Sorry, I added more code now.

Comment: `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getLink);` Where did `getLink` come from?

Comment: How about passing the link as Element item and passing? From adapter you will get the arraylist item based on the position.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Could you write something like this and solve?



              public class Element {
                    private String mNazwa;
                    private String mOpis;
                    private int mImageResourceId;
                    private link;

                    public Element (String nazwa, String opis, int imageResourceId, String link) {
                       mNazwa = nazwa;
                       mOpis = opis;
                       mIntent = intent;
                       this.link = link;
                       mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;
                   }

                   public String getNazwa() {return mNazwa;}
                   public String getOpis() {return mOpis;}
                   public int getmImageResourceId() {return mImageResourceId;}
                }

                public ElementAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

                private ArraList<Element> lstElement;
                public ElementAdapter (ArraList<Element> lstElement) {
                   this.lstElement = lstElement;
                } 

                public onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                // you tag the link with the image;
holder.image.setTag(lstElement.get(position).getLink())
                }

                public onClick(View view) {
                       String tag = view.getTag().toString();
                       Intent browserIntent = new 
                       Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(tag);
                       startActivity(browserIntent);
                  }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolved my problem. Thanks all for reply.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                    Element word = elements.get(position);

                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(word.getUrl()));
                    startActivity(mIntent);
                }
            });
```